# Plotting an exponential distribution with approbriately naming all variables

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I want to insert some arrows into a plot of some exponential distributions:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np


def gauss2d(x,sigma):
    return (1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma ))*np.exp(-1/2*(x/sigma)**2 )

def draw_arrow(zero, sigma, function):
    startx = zero
    print startx,function(sigma, sigma)
    arr = pl.Arrow(startx,function(startx+sigma, sigma), sigma,0,fc="k",ec="k")
    ax = pl.gca()
    ax.add_patch(arr)

def plot_gauss2d():
    x = np.mgrid[115:135:100j]
    #x=np.array(zip(range(5)),dtype=float)
    sigma = 1
    off=1.0
    pl.plot(x,gauss2d(x-126.21,3.56), 'b-')
    draw_arrow(126.21, 3.56, gauss2d)
    pl.plot(x,gauss2d(x-126.71,4.57), 'b-')
    pl.plot(x,gauss2d(x-120.64,3.5), 'b-')
    pl.ylabel('frequency')
    pl.xlabel('ppm of N')
    pl.title
    pl.show()

def main():
    plot_gauss2d()                                                             

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: example1]

Somehow I can't seem to get the arrow right. What I essentially would like to have is something like this:

[image: wish]

what I simply cannot figure out is how to set the arrow straight to where I want it to be. It should mark the point of the standard deviation in the correct height. The whole thing should of course produce multiple exponential curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with arrow is that it uses the `figure` coordinate as compared to the `data` coordinates. Hence, as @Paul have suggested, you can use annotate, as

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np


def gauss2d(x,sigma):
    return (1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma ))*np.exp(-1/2*(x/sigma)**2 )

def markParameters(m,s):
    p1=gauss2d(s,s)
    p2=gauss2d(0,s)

    pl.annotate("", xy=(m-s, p1), xycoords='data', xytext=(m+s, p1), textcoords='data', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", connectionstyle="arc3"),)
    pl.text(m,p1,'sigma',horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='top')
    pl.annotate("", xy=(m, 0), xycoords='data', xytext=(m, p2), textcoords='data', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="<->", connectionstyle="arc3"),)
    pl.text(m,p2*0.75,'mean',horizontalalignment='right',verticalalignment='center',rotation=90)

def plot_gauss2d():
    x = np.mgrid[115:135:100j]
    #x=np.array(zip(range(5)),dtype=float)
    m,s=126,3.56

    pl.plot(x,gauss2d(x-m,s), 'b-')
    markParameters(m,s)

    pl.ylabel('frequency')
    pl.xlabel('ppm of N')
    pl.title
    pl.show()

def main():
    plot_gauss2d()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check out this demo for the `annotate` method:
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/annotation_demo.html

That should take care of what you need.

Comment: actually i do not see how this would help me at all.